# Repeat substring which is trailed by a multiplier expression

Tags: php, string, replace, repeat, hydration

I have a string containing multiple words and I want to expand expressions that indicate multiples of words.

```
$string = '(red, white (X2), green, black, grey (X2))';
```

When a word is immediately followed by `(X2)` (or any integer after `X` wrapped in parentheses), the parenthetical expression should be replaced to display that number of repeated values in total.

The result should be:

```
(red, white, white, green, black, grey, grey)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this is what you're looking for. The example string you wouldn't parse as part of PHP, so I made an assumption that it is a string. The quickest solution is to use regexp or something similar, I avoided that because if you don't know what that is, it might be easier to ingest this solution.

```
$string = "red, white (X2), green, black, grey (X2)";

$words = explode(" " , $string);

$temp = "";
$new_string = array();
foreach ( $words as $w ) {
    if ( strpos($w, "(X2)") !== false ) {
        array_push($new_string , $temp.",");
    } else {
        array_push($new_string , $w);
    }
    $temp = $w;
}

echo implode(" " , $new_string );
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it with a little more control would be to create a `function` such as:

```
function createNewString($string, $delimiter = ', ')
{
    $pieces = explode($delimiter, $string);

    foreach($pieces as $key => $value)
    {   
        if( substr($value, -4) == '(X2)' )
        {
            preg_match('/.+?(?=\(X2\))/', $value, $matches);

            for($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++)
            {
                $newPieces[] = trim($matches[0]);
            }

            continue;
        }

        $newPieces[] = $value;
    }

    return $newString = implode($delimiter, $newPieces);
}
```

You can then pass a simple string wherever you want in your code to the function and get the cleaned string.

```
$string = 'red, white (X2), green, black, grey (X2)';

echo createNewString($string);
```

Output:

`red, white, white, green, black, grey, grey`

This allows you to control the delimiter in case it changes within a string. The output would then use the same delimiter when re-creating the string.

Further, it ensures commas are placed in the correct positions and removes any trailing commas from the end.

Answer (score 0):

I would call upon `preg_replace_callback()` which would leverage `str_repeat()` with the matched substrings.  This is a very direct, reliable, and appropriate technique for this task.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/alRPp))

```
$string = '(red, white (X3), green, black, grey (X2))';

echo preg_replace_callback(
         '/(?:^|,) ([^,]+)\K \(X(\d+)\)/',
         fn($m) => str_repeat(", {$m[1]}", $m[2] - 1),
         $string
     );
```

Output:

```
(red, white, white, white, green, black, grey, grey)
```

`\K` restarts the full string match after matching the original word/color.  Capture group 1 is the color and capture group 2 is the number of repetitions.  Because the original color string is not consumed as part of the fullstring match, the repetition count is reduced by one.

Answer (score 0):

another solution

```
<?php
$string = <<<txt

(red,
white (X2), green, black, grey (X2))


txt;


$s='';
$string=substr(trim($string),1,-1);
$string=str_replace('(X2)','###',$string);
$res=explode(',',$string);
foreach($res as $l){
    
    $s.=(str_contains($l,'###')? ($rpl=str_replace(' ###','',$l)) .','. $rpl : $l ).',';
     
}


echo '('.substr($s,0,-1).')';
?>
```